# Symfony/Form add attribute based on the data

Tags: php, symfony

In one of my custom form types I need to add a custom HTML attribute to the field. However that attribute is based on the data. So I added an event handler but I'm not sure what I should do in it.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    // not sure what to do here.
};
```

Maybe it should be done somewhere else. **Please keep in mind that for my use case I need the data initially set to the form, not the submitted data.**

**EDIT:** I've been asked for some more details of what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I need to put the initial data from database (which are available in the PRE_SET_DATA event) into a `data-*` HTML attribute so that javascript could use it.

**UPDATE: Even after several months there is no good answer so I assume it is currently impossible to solve this.**

Comment: why not pass in the attribute to the form via the controller in `$options` and then conditionally set it?

Comment: Where and how should I conditionally set it?

Comment: see my answer below.  Im hoping this is what you mean, if not let me know.

Answer (score 8):

You can replace your old form-element with new one:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $val = $data['some_field'];
    $options = $form->get('existing_field_name_to_replace')->getConfig()->getOptions();
    $options['attr']['your-attr'] = $val;
    $form->add('existing_field_name_to_replace', 'type', $options);
};
```

`$form->add()` replaces previously defined form field. But you can also use `$form->remove()` and then `$form->add()`.

Comment: That seems like an overkill for somthing simple like this.

Comment: I don't know what do you have and what do you want to achieve but this is the right solution for your request. You want to use event listener and change some attribute. You can't change field and its attributes but you can add new one replacing old one.

Comment: Actually I just need to set the attribute. I don't care if it is done through an event listener or otherwise. I just seemed like a way to go at first sight.

Comment: You can do it many ways. But I think that simplest and easiest to understand way is to use event listener and replace field in the form. It is normal to do things like that. You always can extend this behavior to more complex without needing in some complex refactoring. Sometimes some microseconds of processor time per request help save developers thousands hours. You need just decide for yourself what do you want to achieve and at what cost.

Answer (score 0):

If that's an HTML attribute, you can do it only by editing your view:

```
<div {% if form.DATA_FIELD.vars.value == 'foo' %}disabled{% endif %}>
```

In that case, the `<div>` will be disabled if the data has value "foo" in DATA_FIELD.
If your logic is more complex than a simple check of data attribute, you might want to create a twig extension.

Comment: Did you read the bold sentence at the end of my question? How do I get access to the preset data here? (I believe I can't.)

Comment: I don't understand your questions. You want a way to have an HTML attribute depending on the initial data of your form, is that right?

Comment: Yes and in Twig all I get is the submitted data as far as I know.

Comment: Indeed, but it is also the case in your Controller. Whether you GET or POST the form, the only data you have is the request data. What do you exactly mean by "initial data"? Could you detail a bit more your use case?

Comment: I mean the data that are available in the PRE_SET_DATA event (that is why I tried to use it). In other words it's the data from database which I set to the form using `$form->setData($data);`.

Comment: I've added some more details to the quetion above.

Comment: In that case, I think @Michael Sivolobov's Answer is the best you can have for your use case, even though I would be surprised if there was no better way. But I don't have the full context on your project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to implement the `buildView` method of your form type. This method receives the `FormView` argument which may be used to add any attributes and manipulate the tag class if you need it. It also receives the `Form` instance so you can fetch the data and implement any logic you want.

```php
class MyCustomForm extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, Array $options = []) {
        // Build your form here
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $data = $form->getData();
        // Checking if data exists as the form may be empty
        if($data and $data->isSomething()) {
            $view->vars['attr']['data-foo'] = $data->getBar();
            $view->vars['attr']['class'] .= $data->isBeautiful() ? ' makeBeautiful' : '';
        }
        
        // You may want to access the child views as well
        if($data and $data->hasBeautifulChild()) {
            $view->children['child']->vars['attr']['class'] .= ' makeBeautiful';
        }
    }

}
```

That's it! Symfony call the `buildView` before rendering your form automatically and use the adjusted view to draw the whole thing.

Answer (score -1):

I would not do something as straight forward via a listener for a number of reasons.

1. its complicated to debug/write
2. every listener you add slows down the framework
3. its overkill for most cases

The best way that I can see is to add it via the controller.  As you've provided no use case, I'll make one up for the purposes of illustration.

---

### Use case

You have a field in a form that needs to be either disabled, or enabled depending on whether or not its coping with a new entity, or an edited one.

---

#### Controller

```
public function doSomethingAction(Request $request) {
    
    // ......

    $edit = $this->areWeEditing(); // or whatever data youre trying to inject

    // options to send to the form
    $options = [
        'disable_field' => $edit, // <--- put your data in here.
    ];
    $entity = new Something();
    $form = $this->createForm( SomethingType::class, $entity, $options );

    $form->handleRequest( $request );

    if ( $form->isValid() ) {
        //... do something
    }

    // .....
}
```

---

#### SomethingType.php

```
class SomethingType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {
        $builder->add( 'name', TextType::class, [
            'label'    => 'Name',
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => $options[ 'disable_field' ],  // <---- use the $option here.
        ] )->add( 'email', EmailType::class, [
             'required' => true,
        ] );
    }

    public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver ) {
        $resolver->setDefaults( [
            'data_class'     => Something::class,  // whatever entity class youre mapping to
            'disabled_field' => false,  // you need to set this to tell symfony its an allowed option. Its name needs to match the incoming array key.  If the array key isnt present, this default will be used instead.
        ] );
    }
}
```

The data you pass in can be used either as the array key, or value, or both depending on what youre trying to achieve.

Comment: No I need this to be automatic for my custom form type to work correctly. I can't possibly add a logic like this to every controller where a form with that form type is used.

Comment: without more code to look at its hard to see what youre trying to achieve.  You said 'in one of my forms'.

Comment: Ok. Edited to "one of my custom form types". Thanks. :-)

Comment: As to what I need to achieve - I need to have the data from database available for javascript (as a data-* attribute).

Comment: I would still do it in the controller. and if thats a pain, make a central baseController with a method to use everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I won't use something that ugly. Plus I don't even use the whole symfony so I don't actually have controllers.